# How to test using assertEquals an element of a Set in Java?

Tags: java, set, mockito

I need to make unit testing for a Java method, and I have a Set like this:

```
Set<CreditCard> creditCard = ...
```

And I need to test if an element of this Set is equal with a specific value. It is very easy to do that if creditCard is an ArrayList, I can do something like this:

```
assertEquals(creditCard.get(0).getCreditCardBalance(), CREDIT_CARD_BALANCE);
```

But unfortunately this is a Set and not an ArrayList. How can I test this? Thank you!

Comment: Same question here. Didn't find some good answer so I end up converting a set into the list and then comparing:
`assertEquals(CREDIT_CARD_BALANCE, (new ArrayList<>(creditCard)).get(0))`

Answer (score 0):

Yuu can do something like this:

```
assertTrue(creditCardSet.stream().anyMatch(cc -> cc.getCreditCardBalance() == CREDIT_CARD_BALANCE))
```